# Nokogiri в Ruby как найти всех главных Node и их родителей?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Сразу прошу простить, я новичок в ruby.
У меня есть файл [XML file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akimdi/rubyPractic/master/task1/mddrive.xml)
Нужно пройти по всем потомкам в XML файле, (все что начинается с template name), пишу код, но он не работает. Нужно что бы получился вот такой файл на выходе [out.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akimdi/rubyPractic/master/task1/out.txt)
Я написал решение без nokogiri (оно работает)

```
o = File.new("out.txt","w")
File.open("mddrive.xml") { |f1|
  while get = f1.gets
    temp = get.split(' ')
    if temp[0] == '<template'
      st = temp[1].split('"')
      o.puts(st[1])
    end
  end
}
o.close
```

но вот как переписать с использованием библиотеки, не знаю. 
Пытаюсь как то так: (но ничего не выходит - ниже код не рабочий)

```
require 'nokogiri'
i = File.read("mddrive.xml")
o = File.new("out.txt","w")


doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(inFile))

while node.root
  node.parent
end
```

Comment: А что вы считаете потомками в этом xml?

Comment: все что начинается с <template name=

Comment: в итоге должен получится вот такой файл [файл](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akimdi/myRubyPractic/master/task1/tt)

Comment: добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Comment: добавил информацию в вопрос, пожалуйста помогите мне в этом разобраться

Comment: Ссылка на внешние ресурсы может устареть и тогда ценность вопроса уменьшится. Поэтому добавляйте всю информацию в сам вопрос. Добавьте код который у вас не работает.

Comment: добавил в вопрос код и тот и другой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('mddrive.xml')
x.xpath('//template["name"]').each {|node| puts node.attr("name")}
```